# Diversify result set in solr without grouping

Tags: search, solr

I retrieving results for a specific category from solr 7.7.1 where I want to diversify the results by user. Whenever a visitor is looking at a category, fresh and relevant data from multiple sources should be visible.

The data comes from user imports, and whenever an import finishes, one user is dominating the first page of that category. I want to make sure there is a diverified, but relevant set of offers from many users on the first page.

My current query filters for the category and sorts by price:

```
select?
q=*:*&
start=0&
rows=50&
fq=type:classifieds&
fq={!tag=cat_main}cat_main_id:15&
fl=*,score&
sort=date_created%20desc
```

I tried different sorting by stock availabilty, price and also combined sorting.

```
$this->query->addSortField( 'date_created', SolrQuery::ORDER_DESC  );
// $this->query->addSortField( 'avail_id', SolrQuery::ORDER_DESC  );
// $this->query->addSortField( 'price', SolrQuery::ORDER_ASC  );
```

None of them brought diversity but only worse results.

Then I tried grouping by user_id:

```
$this->query->setGroup(true);
$this->query->addGroupField( 'user_id' );
```

But this not only narrowed down the amount of results within the pagination, but more impotantly returned a different json response which would take a huge effort to rewrite my application.

How can I make sure not to many results are returned from one user?